# Convert object property to number

Tags: javascript, angular, parsing

How can I convert all object properties that are integers from a string to an actual numerical type.

I want the:

1. Lat/Long to be float type
2. Date properties to be numbers

This is a snippet of one object in my array of objects return:

```
Province/State: ""
Country/Region: "US"
Lat: "37.0902"
Long: "-95.7129"
1/22/20: "0"
1/23/20: "0"
1/24/20: "0"
1/25/20: "0"
1/26/20: "0"
1/27/20: "0"
1/28/20: "0"
1/29/20: "0"
1/30/20: "0"
1/31/20: "0"
2/1/20: "0"
2/2/20: "0"
2/3/20: "0"
2/4/20: "0"
2/5/20: "0"
2/6/20: "0"
2/7/20: "0"
2/8/20: "0"
```

Edit: Thank you very much to all of the responses! I love seeing the different methods of solutions. I know I'll run into this problem again so it's great to know how to get past it now.

Comment: convert it using parseFloat or even a unary +

Comment: What's the format of the numbers you want the dates converted into?

Comment: @enhzflep No I wasn't interested in changing the keys of the object itself. I was interested in changing the type of the objects' values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```js
const provinceData = {
  "Province/State": "",
  "Country/Region": "US",
  Lat: "37.0902",
  Long: "-95.7129",
  "1/22/20": "0",
  "1/23/20": "0",
  "1/24/20": "0",
  "1/25/20": "0",
  "1/26/20": "0",
  "1/27/20": "0",
  "1/28/20": "0",
  "1/29/20": "0",
  "1/30/20": "0",
  "1/31/20": "0",
  "2/1/20": "0",
  "2/2/20": "0",
  "2/3/20": "0",
  "2/4/20": "0",
  "2/5/20": "0",
  "2/6/20": "0",
  "2/7/20": "0",
  "2/8/20": "0",
};
let formatedProvinceData = {};

for (const property in provinceData) {
  const unusedObjectValues = ["Province/State", "Country/Region"];

  formatedProvinceData = unusedObjectValues.includes(property)
    ? { ...formatedProvinceData, [property]: provinceData[property] }
    : { ...formatedProvinceData, [property]: parseFloat(provinceData[property]) };
}

console.log(formatedProvinceData)
```

Comment: Wow, never thought of using a ternary operator in this case. Simple and straight to the point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 'for...in' loop to modify each property. I'm testing for your date property using a `.split()` method which makes an array of the string. If the resulting array (split on `/`) is of length three then it converts the value to an int type.

```js
const x = {
  "Province/State": "",
  "Country/Region" : "US",
  "Lat" : "37.0902",
  "Long" : "-95.7129",
  "1/22/20" : "0",
  "1/23/20": "0",
  "1/24/20": "0",
  "1/25/20": "0",
  "1/26/20": "0",
  "1/27/20": "0",
  "1/28/20": "0",
  "1/29/20": "0",
  "1/30/20": "0",
  "1/31/20": "0",
  "2/1/20": "0",
  "2/2/20": "0",
  "2/3/20": "0",
  "2/4/20": "0",
  "2/5/20": "0",
  "2/6/20": "0",
  "2/7/20": "0",
  "2/8/20": "0"
}


function returnModifiedObject(theObject) {

  const newObject = {...theObject} //spread syntax makes copy of object contents
  newObject["Lat"] = parseFloat(newObject["Lat"])
  newObject["Long"] = parseFloat(newObject["Long"])

  for (const prop in newObject) {
    if(prop.split("/").length === 3){
        newObject[prop] = parseInt(newObject[prop])
      }
  }
  
  return newObject
}

const y = returnModifiedObject(x)
console.log(y)
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function converter(obj) {

const entries = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
if(key === 'Lat' || key === 'Long') {
return [key, parseFloat(obj[key])];
}
const date = new Date(key);
return date.getDate() !== date.getDate() ? [key, obj[key]] : [key, Number(obj[key])];
})

return Object.fromEntries(new Map(entries));
}


const data = {
'Province/State': "",
'Country/Region': "US,",
'Lat': "37.0902",
'Long': "-95.7129",
'1/22/20': "0",
'1/23/20': "0",
'1/24/20': "0",
'1/25/20': "0",
'1/26/20': "0",
'1/27/20': "0",
'1/28/20': "0",
'1/29/20': "0",
'1/30/20': "0",
'1/31/20': "0",
'2/1/20': "0",
'2/2/20': "0",
'2/3/20': "0",
'2/4/20': "0",
'2/5/20': "0",
'2/6/20': "0",
'2/7/20': "0",
'2/8/20': "0",
}
console.log(converter(data));
```

Comment: What's the need for 'return date.getDate() !== date.getDate() ? [key, obj[key]] : [key, Number(obj[key])]; })'